# Given a group homomorphism $\phi :G \to G'$, show that if $|G'|$ is finite, then $|\phi[G]|$ is finite and is a divisor of $|G'|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **The Theorem of Lagrange:** Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$.  Then the order of $H$ is a divisor of the order of $G$.

We know that $\phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $[G']$, correct?
So, if we suppose $|G'|$ is finite, then we also are supposing $|\phi[G]$|is finite.  Then according to Lagrange's Theorem we see $|\phi[G]|$ divides $|G']$?

- *Does this complete the proof?*
- *Is it necessary to prove $\phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $[G']$, and if so how would we do this?*

I am aware of the properties a subgroup must have, but this seemed somewhat intuitive.

We are supposing that $|G'|$ finite, and this would immediately make $\phi[G]$ finite, because how could a subgroup have more elements than the group itself?

Some more explanation would be great.

Comment: What is $[G]$ ?

Comment: Your reasoning is okay. If it has not been mentioned before that the image of a grouphomomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain then for completeness that fact should be proved. It is straightforward on base of: $\phi(a)\phi(b)^{-1}=\phi(ab^{-1})\in\text{im}\phi$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to prove that G is a subgroup of G'?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that it is plain that $\varphi(G)$ is finite if $G'$ is finite, as a subset of a finite set is always finite and $\varphi(G) \subset G'$.

The line of reasoning that $\varphi(G)$ is  a subgroup and then invoking Lagrange's theorem is also fine.

Yet, I do think you should show that $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup, except you saw that result already and thus use it. It is not hard to show; a way to do it is outlined in a comment.